# How to get a code sign key for Android App

Tags: android, apk, code-signing

Android Developers website has the following in "Signing Your Applications" article:

> If you plan to publish your application(s) on Google Play, note that a
>   validity period ending after 22 October 2033 is a requirement. You can
>   not upload an application if it is signed with a key whose validity
>   expires before that date.

That sounds great when you add self-signed keys. But what about getting an official key for a company? Regular *Code Sign certificate* costs around 130$ per year. Multiply that by at least 20, giving 2600$ just for the key. Which may not seem much for a big company, but a startup will struggle with this.

Is self-signed key an only solution?

Comment: What's the benefit of paying for an "official" key?

Comment: The "benefit" to keys signed by a trusted 3rd party only exist in systems that verify them, which Android does not. For that reason, it would be a waste of money to have your Android app key signed by a 3rd party.

Comment: Hm. Okay. Does it make no difference at all for the end-user, device, Google Play and other involved parties? Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Self signing is perfectly fine. Since your end-users will never be able to verify the certificate.

Answer (score -2):

Nope. Even though it may seem like it at first. There is little or no information about third-parties offering long-term keys just for Android Developers. For 500$ you get an infinite number of sign operations with up to 25 year ahead expiry date. Symantec offers such service.